# replace all ocurances in text that are not followed by a number

Tags: regex, vb.net, file, text, replace

I have a textbox where a user writes basically anything. This text needs to be searched and replaced inside a txt file. But only those ocurances that are not followed by a number are suposed to be replaced. So for instance if the textbox contains "hello2" then every ocurrance of "hello2" in the txt file needs to be replaced with "customtext1" but if for example it finds "hello23" inside the txt file it is not suposed to replace it. Opening the file, making a search and replace etc. is not a problem. Problem is to check if the next char is a number. And it might also be a problem if hello2 is the last word of a row or the file, so it has no character following it. How can I do this the easy way?

Thanks

edit:

The word that gets replaced must have either a whitespace, or a symbol such as .,!?/-_ or be the beginning of a row.

Comment: what will be your expected output if the content in the file is `hello2 hello hello2 hello21 hello20 2hello2`

Comment: the output would be `customtext1 hello customtext1 hello21 hello20 2hello2` in fact now that you show this (didnt think of it) it must have a whitespace in front or be the beginning of a row. will update the question right away

Comment: I think this can be done using regular expressions but that's not my forte. Might help by adding RegEx as a tag to highlight the question amongst regex experts.

Comment: added regex tag! thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[\n .,!?/-_]hello2[\n .,!?/-_]
```

I think this regex should work for what you described would be nice to have some sample text to test it

Comment: thanks! will test it and report back! will this work also if there is nothing at the end of the row? if for example hello2 is the last word of the txt file?

Comment: something is off here.. i have this now: `content = Regex.Replace(content, "[\n .,!?/_]" & DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "[\n .,!?/-_]", "customtext" & j)` problem is that this removes also the characters in front and after the hello2 word...

Comment: You need to put the part that you want replaced into brackets so that it be inside a capture group like this here now when you access capture group [0] or [1] (depending on where you are doing this) it will just access the hello2 word, [\n .,!?/-_](hello2)[\n .,!?/-_],

Comment: not sure i understand... how can i access it in the regex replace context? i mean, the [0] where is that suposed to be??

Comment: As i said depends on where you are doing this and the syntax just write into google "your program language" regex capture group

Comment: Here is a example on how it works in C# **Match match = Regex.Match("nothinginputnothing", "nothing(input)nothing");**
              **string result = match.Groups[1].Value;** If you had more stuff between other () then that would be Groups[2] and so on

Comment: got it working.. just a minor problem with the regex: the first hello2 is not replaced because there is nothing in front of it,